# jQuery Colorbox css issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, colorbox

I'm using colorbox jquery plugin for lightbox. Everything works great except that there is a minor problem with only chrome. When a user clicks a link to get the colorbox, it should look like the first image. When a user clicks a new link with a different url, the colorbox appears like the second image. I looked at the css and it looks just fine and it only happens on Chrome. Do I have problem with my css?

[image]

[image]

```
  #cboxTopLeft{width:90px; height:43px; background:url(images/videocontrols.png) no-repeat 0 0; position: absolute; left: -60px; }
    #cboxTopRight{width:90px; height:43px; background:url(images/videocontrols.png) no-repeat -91px 0; position: absolute; right:-16px; }
    #cboxBottomLeft{width:91px; height:46px; background:url(images/videocontrols.png) no-repeat 0 -47px; position: absolute; left:-60px; bottom:-12px;}
    #cboxBottomRight{width:91px; height:57px; background:url(images/videocontrols.png) no-repeat -91px -47px; position: absolute; right: -16px;  bottom:-23px;}
```

Comment: Why are they absolutely positioned?

Comment: Most likely a misunderstanding about spriting technique. => Moon, inspect the elements in Chrome when this occurs. Open a Developer Tools console. Inspect Resources to see if the imgs are loaded (I suspect they are..); If they are present, you most likely have a positioning error; if the images are not loaded, you should pursue that vector.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try clearing your cache or checking if the corner image files are being loadedin the network tab of chrome??

Comment: Yes, I cleared cache and tried more than 10 times. The image also shows up on the network tab (it must since the first link works just fine).

Comment: What about when you inspect the element, is it postioned correctly on Chrome? As in do you need a container with a position:relative??

Comment: // when I inspect the element, it has the correct styles. The funny thing is...when I uncheck any of its styles (top, right, position, or whatever..) then check it again, it fixes itself.